# Async methods switching passing control back and forth to next async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have two async methods that retrieve data from two tables in a database. During runtime, I got an error

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

I stepped into my code and realized something strange, the two methods switch control back and forth even before a method finishes executing. Method 1 would execute and after two or three lines, method 2 executes then after a few lines control goes back to method 1. This happens until I get that exception. Funny thing though is that while posting this, I ran the application and I got no Exception. Here are the two methods

```
public async void InitializeParts()
{
    populator = new Populator();
    await Task.Run(()=> detailsDataTable = new DataTable());
    string partSql = "SELECT * FROM tblparts";            
    await Task.Run(() => populator.FillDataTableAsync(partSql, detailsDataTable));
    await Task.Run(() => partDetailsDataGridView.DataSource = detailsDataTable);
    detailsCriteriaSearchBox.Text = string.Empty;
}

public async void InitializeTrack()
{
    populator = new Populator();
    await Task.Run(() => trackDataTable = new DataTable());
    string TrackSql = "SELECT * FROM tblmodule";
    await Task.Run(() => populator.FillDataTableAsync(TrackSql, trackDataTable));
    await Task.Run(() => trackModulesDataGridView.DataSource = trackDataTable);
    trackCriteriaSearchBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

I call the two  methods one after the other like this

```
await Task.Run(() => InitializeParts());
await Task.Run(() => InitializeTrack());
```

My question is what exactly is happening as I want to handle it.

Comment: All those `Task.Run` inside the methods are also rather bad. The 1st and 3rd should just be removed (made synchronous) and the 2nd should be changed into a simple `await` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public async void InitializeParts()
```

This is an asynchronous method that does not return a `Task` and so can't be awaited on.

```
await Task.Run(() => InitializeParts());
```

This creates a `Task` that can be awaited on, which then calls the above method that cannot. As such, that `Task` will return after starting `InitializeParts()` but not after waiting for `InitializeParts()` to complete. (Most likely after the first `await` within `InitializeParts()`.

Change `public async void InitializeParts()` to `public async Task InitializeParts()`.

Also, when you do something like:

```
await Task.Run(() => populator.FillDataTableAsync(partSql, detailsDataTable));
```

Then you are creating a task that calls another task, but doesn't wait on it, and then waiting on that "outer" task. This should just be:

```
await populator.FillDataTableAsync(partSql, detailsDataTable);
```

Change `await Task.Run(() => InitializeParts());` to `await InitializeParts();`.

Do the equivalent with the other method.

Now you will be `await`ing the whole task.

> Funny thing though is that while posting this, I ran the application and I got no Exception.

Your problem is that you've asynchronous code that depends on an order between two parts of it, and you're not correctly forcing that order. There's nothing to say it won't sometimes just happen to operate in the correct order, there's just nothing to guarantee that it will, either.

Comment: Do you recommend using Wait() on the void async methods?

Comment: @Dennis you should not use `async void` except for event handlers. The asynchronous equivalent to a void method is `async Task`.

Comment: I recommend not having void async methods in the first place, void async methods are only useful for event handlers or other cases where they are never going to be waited on. Change them to `async Task` and the `async` will automatically wrap their returning void to returning `Task`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `async void` which basically means that your calls:

```
await Task.Run(() => InitializeParts());
await Task.Run(() => InitializeTrack());
```

Are happening immediately after one another, so `InitializeTrack()` is **not** waiting for `InitializeParts()` to complete.

This is an established part of the TPL.

More information on best practices and why async void should usually be avoided is over on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

You can fix this by just changing them to `async Task` and then waiting for them to complete will work.

Comment: Thanks for the link am going through it. Just asking though, since my two async method returns void, should I use Wait() to ensure that each runs to completion first before the other is executed?

Comment: @Dennis no, returning Task is equivalent to returning nothing, but it provides the underlying async/await mechanism with a handle to wait on, it will essentially do what you're describing for you (sort of). Unless you have a specific reason to, you should probably never manually wait a task as this will block and defeat the purpose of tasks.

Comment: @Dennis think of it this way: return void = `async Task` return value = `async Task<T>` where T is the type you're returning.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is what exactly is happening

What is happening is that you are using multiple thread-pool threads to execute your DB calls, and as your method is marked `async void`, You actually don't `await` on the inner `Task.Run` calls (and their generated tasks, because you *can't*. That is why you're seeing the first and the second "race" each other to completion.

There are a couple of things you should consider doing differently.

First, and most important, don't use `async void`, always use `async Task`. The former is ment only for compatibility with event handlers (which isn't the case here), and causes your async method to be in a "fire and forget" fashion, which is clearly what you don't want here.

Second, don't use the [async over sync](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) anti-pattern. If your method is synchronous, and you want to queue it on a threadpool thread, do so at the top-most of your call-stack. Don't expose a `XXXAsync` method which will make the caller think this call is actually asynchronous (which it isn't here):

```
public void InitializeParts()
{
    populator = new Populator();
    detailsDataTable = new DataTable();
    string partSql = "SELECT * FROM tblparts";            
    populator.FillDataTable(partSql, detailsDataTable);
    partDetailsDataGridView.DataSource = detailsDataTable;
    detailsCriteriaSearchBox.Text = string.Empty;
}

public void InitializeTrack()
{
    populator = new Populator();
    trackDataTable = new DataTable();
    string TrackSql = "SELECT * FROM tblmodule";
    populator.FillDataTable(TrackSql, trackDataTable);
    trackModulesDataGridView.DataSource = trackDataTable;
    trackCriteriaSearchBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

And now:

```
await Task.Run(() => InitializeParts());
await Task.Run(() => InitializeTrack());
```

Now, as you're querying a database, which is an asynchronous IO call, you **need not use** `Task.Run` at all. You can use the natural async API exposed by the database provider:

```
public async Task InitializePartsAsync()
{
    populator = new Populator();
    detailsDataTable = new DataTable();

    string partSql = "SELECT * FROM tblparts"; 
    await populator.FillDataTableAsync(partSql, detailsDataTable);

    partDetailsDataGridView.DataSource = detailsDataTable;
    detailsCriteriaSearchBox.Text = string.Empty;
}

public async Task InitializeTrackAsync()
{
    populator = new Populator();
    trackDataTable = new DataTable();

    string TrackSql = "SELECT * FROM tblmodule";
    await populator.FillDataTableAsync(TrackSql, trackDataTable);

    trackModulesDataGridView.DataSource = trackDataTable;
    trackCriteriaSearchBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Now, when you call them, there is no reason to use `Task.Run`, because the major IO work `FillDataTableAsync`, is done asynchronously, without consuming any threads:

```
await InitializePartsAsync();
await InitializeTrackAsync();
```